# Android:: What to do to allow forceful kill of service

Tags: android, service

I have service running in background and notification is shown in GUI.
When i do force close from application=>manage application, my
service, application and icon in notification bar goes off.

But when i kill my application via TaskKiller application, my service
stopped and then Android OS restarts service(i can see from logcat)
and icon in my notification area remains. while my background work (of
downloading image) is closed.

I return START_STICKY (also tried with STArT_NOT_STICKY flag) from
OnStartCommand(), but no luck. My GUI activity, binds to service via
Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, is it because of that flag?

What should i do if i want my application,service and notification
area icon to go off, when application is killed by task killer.

**Solution**

resolved this issue by using flag in intent passed to Service when started from activity. When OS restarts service after crash/task killer, Service receives null intent

Answer (score 1):

my first question would be why you want your service to be killed by a taskkiller? or in other words, why you need to have your service killed via a taskkiller? it should be your intention to run your service only as long as you need it and then shut it off at the right time using stopSelf(), stopService() or stopForeground() (you will need one of these, depending on how you started it and how you want to stop it). but i can not give you a suggestion how to do that if i do not know what you are actually doing.

my guess is that you did not unbind from the service in your activity so the service is going to be restarted by the android system automatically. that is, because your service is rated as necessary for your activity. to confirm that guess, please post a logcat output here.

Comment: Thanks markus, I was checking if my application terminates cleanly and starts normally after some abrupt thing happen like my app killed by some task killer app. I  resolved this issue by using flag in intent passed to Service when started from activity. When OS restarts service after crash/task killer, Service receives null intent.